# Dereferencing **this and setting *this to zero?

Tags: c++, pointers, constructor, reverse-engineering, dereference

**this is getting dereferenced then it's value set to zero. Can someone explain what is happening here? One of these functions is constructor of some struct, I'm wondering which.

```
void **__thiscall PossiblyCtor1(void **this)
{
  void **ret;
  ret = this;
  *this = 0; // <- HERE
  PossiblyCtor2(this);
  return ret;
}
```

It was called in middle of some other function after malloc:

```
--- unimportant code ---

v43 = (void **)Allocate(4u, v46, v47);
if ( v43 )
  v44 = PossiblyCtor1(v43); // <- CALL
else
  v44 = 0;

--- unimportant code ---
```

Forgive me stupid names, but this is reverse engineered code from IDA.

Comment: `v43` is a pointer to (a pointer on the heap). If the allocation succeeded, it calls `PossiblyCtor1`, which sets the second pointer (the one on the heap), to `NULL`.  What's the confusion?

Comment: @ThomasMatthews: This is reverse engineered code, and not valid C nor C++.

Comment: @MooingDuck wait, so it's setting NULL as "value" of already heap allocated pointer, then sending that NULL ptr as this/ecx to the constructor of some struct. So it would mean that PossiblyCtor2 is actual constructor?

Comment: Too little information to tell, but if the names are accurate, the yes. Maybe the 2 is a derived class or chained constructor. Or maybe not.

Comment: @MooingDuck names aren't necessarily accurate, I renamed them myself, only Allocate, which is something like malloc, comes from IDA. But one thing is sure, the `v44` returned from `PossiblyCtor1` is assigned to pointer of known (to me) struct, later in code. The actual object is constructed in `PossiblyCtor2`, so I was wondering what is the purpose of `PossiblyCtor1` function? Some kind of wrapper?

Comment: Yes, maybe it's some kind of wrapper class. Or maybe a derived class. Or maybe a chained constructor.  Impossible to tell without seeing more uses of the pointer, and probably impossible to tell even then.

Comment: @MooingDuck it looks like valid C (allowing for the calling convention specifier extension)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Solved] It is setting NULL as "value" of already heap allocated pointer (thanks Mooing Duck for help), then sending that NULL ptr as "this" to the constructor of some object.

`PossiblyCtor1` is an actual constructor.